# Better R way of doing/replacing the following for loop

Tags: r

Just for educational reasons, is there an R better way (something with ?apply instead of the for loop) for the following? Been breaking my head but can't see the "solution".

```
foo_length <- 10
foo_list <- list("1"=c(1, 3, 4), "2"=c(2, 5, 9), "3"=c(6, 7, 8, 10))
foo <- rep(NA_integer_, foo_length)
for (iname in names(foo_list))
  foo[foo_list[[iname]]] <- as.integer(iname)
```

Output of `foo` is `1 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 3`

Comment: whats your desired output

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh just run the code and the desired output is in `foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
lens <- sapply(foo_list,length)             ## lengths of components
foo <- numeric(foo_length)                  ## result vector (empty)
v <- rep(as.integer(names(foo_list)),lens)  ## matching vector
foo[unlist(foo_list)] <- v                  ## assign matching values
```

?

Comment: Nice idea! Similar option would be `rep(as.integer(names(foo_list)), lengths(foo_list))[order(unlist(foo_list))]`

Comment: Thanks both :). Works with all cases, @docendodiscimus has pointed out in other answers that "fail" with more than 1 digits.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative:

```
with(stack(foo_list), as.integer(as.character(ind))[order(values)] )
# 1 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 3
```

To see how it works, look at various steps...

- `s = stack(foo_list)`
- `s[order(s$values),]`
- `s$ind[order(s$values)]`

and read `?with`, `?stack`, `?factor` and `?order`.

Comment: Thanks and for the pointers too :). Seems also to be working only with single digit names, but it is really nice and short.

Comment: @John I don't follow what you're saying about the number of digits.

Comment: `foo_list <- list("11"=c(1, 3, 4), "22"=c(2, 5, 9), "33"=c(6, 7, 8, 10))`

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll edit. Factor variables causing trouble again!

Comment: Anyway, in my opinion, @rawr's answer was the best. Not sure why his comment's gone.

Comment: Also magic. Now works :). Hard for me, being a novice to judge, which one should be the "accepted" answer, but this and the ones above all work and are magic.

Comment: Heh, glad to hear they work. Sounds like good motivation to learn magic. Fyi, if you have quick questions about R, there is a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
as.integer(sapply(strsplit(names(sort(unlist(foo_list))),split = ""),`[`,1))
# [1] 1 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 3
```

Comment: The result is correct but I doubt that it's better / more efficient way than using the preallocated for loop. Also, you'll be in trouble if the list names are >1 digits

Comment: @docendodiscimus : Definitely. I am not satisfied with my own post. I will delete that.

Comment: I don't think it should be deleted. It's fine.

Comment: Also, don't think it should be deleted either as the post aim was "educational" and every solution has something to learn from :).